# Concavity of smallest positive eigenvalue of a semidefinite matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, convex-analysis, positive-semidefinite, singular-values

Let $A\in\mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ be positive semidefinite with rank $n<d$. Hence $A$ is not positive definite. Is the function
$$ A \mapsto \lambda^{+}_{\text{min}}(A)$$
concave? Here $\lambda^{+}_{\text{min}}(A)$ denotes the smallest positive eigenvalue of $A$.

Comment: What domain are you using for $\lambda_\min^+$?

Comment: If you restrict to the space of positive semi definite matrices then the function is concave. Note that $\lambda_\min^+(A) = \min_{\|x\|=1} x^T Ax$.

Comment: You need to clarify the meaning of "concave function" here, as the set of all PSD $A$ of rank $n$ is not convex. In particular, given two rank-$n$ PSD matrices $A$ and $B$, the matrices lying on the line segment joining $A$ and $B$ can have ranks greater than $n$.

Comment: @user1551, can you think of a "reasonable'' subset of the set of PSD matrices of rank n, which is convex? In connection to how one should define "reasonable", my end goal is to have a distributional assumption on a random matrix $X\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times d}$ so that I can apply Jensen's inequality in the sense $\mathbb{E}[\lambda^{+}_{\text{min}}(X^TX)] \leq \lambda^{+}_{\text{min}}(\mathbb{E}[X^TX])$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Denote the set of all rank-$n$ positive semidefinite matrices by $\mathcal P_n$. The answer to your question is “yes” on each convex subset of $\mathcal P_n$.

We first remark that $\mathcal P_n$ is **not** convex. In particular, given two rank-$n$ PSD matrices  $A$ and $B$, the matrices lying on the line segment $[A,B]=\{(1-t)A+tB:0\leq t\leq 1\}$ can have ranks greater than $n$.

However, if all matrices in $[A,B]$ have the same rank $n$, then $A,B$ and $(1-t)A+tB$ have the same nullity (namely, $d-n$). Since
$$
\ker\left((1-t)A+tB\right)
=\ker(A)\cap\ker(B)\tag{1}
$$
when $0<t<1$, we must have $\ker(A)=\ker(B)=\ker\left((1-t)A+tB\right)$. Conversely, if $\ker(A)=\ker(B)$, $(1)$ shows that all matrices on $[A,B]$ share the same null space and the same range.

It follows that if we define an equivalence relation on $\mathcal P_n$ by $A\sim B$ if and only if $\ker(A)=\ker(B)$, the equivalence classes are precisely the maximal convex subsets of $\mathcal P_n$. Let $A\sim B$ and $V=\ker(A)^\perp$. For any $t\in[0,1]$, let $C=(1-t)A+tBx$. Then
\begin{aligned}
\lambda_\min^+(C)
&=\min_{x\perp\ker(C),\,\|x\|=1}x^TCx\\
&=\min_{x\in V,\,\|x\|=1}x^TCx\\
&=\min_{x\in V,\,\|x\|=1}x^T\left[(1-t)A+tB\right]x\\
&\ge\min_{x\in V,\,\|x\|=1}(1-t)x^TAx
+\min_{x\in V,\,\|x\|=1}tx^TBx\\
&=\min_{x\perp\ker(A),\,\|x\|=1}(1-t)x^TAx
+\min_{x\perp\ker(B),\,\|x\|=1}tx^TBx\\
&=(1-t)\lambda_\min^+(A)+t\lambda_\min^+(B).\\
\end{aligned}
Hence $\lambda_\min^+$ is concave on such an equivalence class.

Comment: Excellent! Thank you very much. Could you also please give a reference or explanation to what is meant by a "maximal convex subset"?

Comment: @vladye It is not a special technical term. What I meant is that the equivalence class of $A$ is the largest convex subset of $\mathcal P_n$ that contains $A$. Any convex set in $\mathcal P_n$ that contains $A$ must be a subset of the equivalence class of $A$.

Answer (score 0):

The function is concave over the space of symmetric matrices. The formulation of @copper.hat shows that the function is concave because it is the minimum of concave (even linear) functions.

Comment: I don't think this is true. Consider the $2\times 2$ matrices, $A,B$, which have all entries zero other than $A_{11} = 1$, $B_{22} = 1$. Then $\lambda^{+}_{\text{min}}(At+B(1-t)) = \text{min}(t,1-t) \leq 1 = \lambda^{+}_{\text{min}}(At) + \lambda^{+}_{\text{min}}(B(1-t))$. Both $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite and so is $At + B(1-t)$. I think the point of @user1551 is important.